# getting Operation `todos.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms when trying to save data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, runtime-error

```
const express=require("express");
const { stringify } = require("querystring");
const router= express.Router()
const Db=require("../models/Db")

router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index.hbs");

})
.post("/addData",async(req,res)=>{
    const data=req.body
    console.log(data);
    try{
        const todo= new Db({
            title:req.body.title,
            query:req.body.query,
        })
        const result= await Db.create(todo)
        console.log("data saved")
        console.log(todo.title)
        console.log(todo.query)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/")
})
```

//this shows Operation `todos.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms when trying to save data
//plz help me here

```
const express=require("express");
const { stringify } = require("querystring");
const router= express.Router()
const Db=require("../models/Db")

router.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index.hbs");

})
.post("/addData",async(req,res)=>{
    const data=req.body
    console.log(data);
    try{
        const todo= new Db({
            title:req.body.title,
            query:req.body.query,
        })
        const result= await todo.save
        console.log("data saved")
        console.log(todo.title)
        console.log(todo.query)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/")
})


module.exports=router
```

//here i am not getting error but data is not added to database plz help me  here
/// here it doesnt shows any error but no data gets saved when i check mongodb compass

Comment: what about this error :-MongooseError: Operation `todos.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\current pro\crud2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
database is connected

Answer (score 0):

thanks i solved the timeout error by changing from
const DATABASE_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myNewDb"
to
const DATABASE_URL="mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/myNewDb"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).